# Exploit on HTTPS, how change https form value

Tags: php, security, exploit

I'm e-commerce developer and have a problem, at certain part of the purchase my code generate a submit form with the purchase info. And send to payment gateway.

This form is generated on PHP and after its generate he write

```
document.getElementById('formnid').submit();
```

I'm having problem because somebody are sending discount value to gateway, and i don't know how.

At certain point my project save a log, after generate this form and submit it. And on my log everything is allright. So i suppous he change the value between my send information and gateway geting the info.

Somebody can give me a light i need discovery how he doing this.

Ty in advance

Answer (score 1):

Never trust the values that come on the form, the value must be always be set\validated on the server side. From what I gathered you are passing the value as a hidden field on the form, and the user is simply altering that.

Answer (score 1):

When the payment confirmation comes back from the gateway you should check that the actual amount paid matches the amount that should have been paid.
Only then has the user paid. It's fine to post prices along with your form but it must always be checked upon completion.

Answer (score 1):

If the pricing / discount information is hidden on the DOM (via hidden inputs, for example), manipulating the DOM using Chrome's "Developer's Toolbar" or Firefox's "Firebug" is trivial, allowing for any end user to make changes to those hidden inputs without reprieve.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But php generate the "<form>" and submit very fast. It'st hard stop on exactly point with firebug or similar. But it's probably, the problem is there.